# what is the proper sql for showing an employees name then the max salary of the whole table?

Tags: oracle11g

Given that I need to find Eleni from the table(which I know how to), the next thing to be done is to show the max salary of the entire employee record which is from Steven with a value of 24000, the thing is I always get the salary of Eleni which is 10500. How do I show the max salary of Steven?

```
SELECT
    LASTNAME || ',' || FIRSTNAME,
    MAX(SALARY)
FROM
    EMPLOYEES
WHERE
    LASTNAME LIKE 'Z%'
GROUP BY
    LASTNAME,
    FIRSTNAME,
    SALARY;
```

output:

```
LASTNAME||','||FIRSTN MAX(SALARY)
--------------------- -----------
ZLOTKEY,ELENI               10500
```

output should be:

```
LASTNAME||','||FIRSTN MAX(SALARY)
--------------------- -----------
ZLOTKEY,ELENI               24000
```

Comment: So you want some random person's name, and the max salary of all employees?

Comment: I suggest you use the `AS` operator to rename your columns. Also the ISO SQL method for concatenation is the `CONCAT` function and not the `||` operator.

Comment: You need to show us your raw data in the `EMPLOYEES` table - You have `LASTNAME LIKE 'Z%'` - Steven's data won't show unless his last name also starts with a 'Z' character, which you haven't confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will give you the max salary for the whole table:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(CONCAT(LASTNAME, ','), FIRSTNAME) AS FULLNAME,
    MAXSALARY
FROM
    EMPLOYEES, (SELECT MAX(SALARY) AS MAXSALARY FROM EMPLOYEES)
WHERE
    LASTNAME LIKE 'Z%';
```

But as other commentators have said, this will only give you want you want as long as Eleni is the only Employee with a surname starting with 'Z' .  As soon as you employ Paul Zisman, your query will no longer return just one record.  In this case, though, the Max(Salary) will be shown twice.